# Why is this question marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005359/error-double-free-or-corruption-fasttop-caused-by-destructor-but-how) question, which was marked as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) question. Although knowing the information in the answer of the second question would have solved my problem, I don't think that this constitutes duplication. In the same way, "Why is the sky blue?" isn't a duplicate of "What is Rayleigh scattering?" even though knowing the information in the second question would answer the first.

I am under the impression that a question is flagged as a duplicate when it presents the same issue as another, similar question. In this case, I would have had to already know what a "copy constructor" is to look up "the rule of three," or how different C++ equal-sign is from Python's! Not that the answer to the other question wasn't extremely helpful, but it seems like I'd have to accidentally stumble over it to have seen it as relevant to my question.

I think that answer could have been linked as a reference, like linking a Wikipedia article or something.

Is this duplicate flag a reasonable one?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: Did the duplicate answer your question?  If so then yes it was appropriate.

Comment: As an aside, your question fails on main fails the "minimal" part of [mcve]. If you had worked on that, you might have discovered the solution yourself. Or at least come closer.

Comment: @Deduplicator I wouldn't have come any closer, unfortunately. I knew exactly where the problem occurred, and it wasn't in either of the imported classes. I was going to write very simple 'Node' and 'Item' classes to throw into the question—but I thought that'd be unecessary code bloat. I was incorrect, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question has been closed as a duplicate of a so-called "canonical Q&A".

Issues that occur often and get multiple questions asked about daily, usually get closed as dupe of a canonical Q&A. The wall of text in the canonical post may look a bit overwhelming, but it's everything you need to know to recognize the issue and learn to prevent it in the future.

In the .NET tags, there's [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). No matter the cause, if you ask a question about your code throwing a `NullReferenceException`, the answer is the same: see duplicate, go debugging.

Comment: We use the same [tactic in the Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/) tag.

Answer (score 8):

> *"I am under the impression that a question is flagged as a duplicate when it presents the same issue as another, similar question."*

Your impression is right, that was the reason why I have closed your question.

> *"Not that the answer to the other question wasn't extremely helpful, but it seems like I'd have to accidentally stumble over it to have seen it as relevant to my question."*

I have some (decades) of experience in the language, and I'm able to spot patterns of questions (even incomplete) stating errors as you've experienced. It was my intend to point you to a helpful answer.

The downvotes on your question most probably came, because it was incomplete (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not because it was marked as duplicate.

Comment: Funny. :P But, I *obviously* don't see why, and question your judgement regarding my post. This answer doesn't provide any actual information—the upvoting and downvoting habits of Stack Overflow are increasingly confusing.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy Updated my answer a bit for clarification.

Comment: I appreciate that! Thank you.